# Problem to run my app in Apple Watch Simulator

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watch, stub

The error is: Watch-Only Application Stubs are not available when building for WatchOS.

Someone know how to fix this? I tried to find about this issue everywhere but I couldn't find anything helpful.

I tried a lot of things but none of them worked.

Comment: You should add more information. Like the last part of the whole build execution code.

Answer (score 0):

Goto your project menu settings.

Under Targets choose your main app target.eg my_watch

Then goto Supported Platforms.

Your selected target column will be there.

Change this to iOS.

[Attachment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q5Ir.png)